# Is a context manager exited if a generator is garbage collected?

Tags: python, generator, contextmanager

Suppose we have a simple generator like this:

```
def generator():
    with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
        yield f.readline()
        yield f.readline()
```

and use it like this to get a single element/line:

```
line = next(generator())
```

Is the context manager closed once the temporary generator object becomes garbage collected?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, ...why _wouldn't_ it be? If there's no more handle on the generator, how is the reference count on the file above zero? I'd expect it to be closed even if there _weren't_ a context manager in use.

Comment: @MadPhysicist So the answer is no? Why so snappy? I believe this to be a valid question

Comment: ...which is to say, the only problem I have with this question is "is the file closed?" doesn't strictly answer "is the context manager exited?" -- the file can be closed even if the context manager's `__exit__` isn't called. (Though indeed I expect it _will_ be called, and it certainly is easy to test).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Valid point. Obviously the file is only supposed to be a placeholder for a context manager. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `with` statement has the same semantics as a `try` statement, with some additional code execute aside from the body of the `with` statement itself. From [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement%22)

> The following code:
>
> ```
> with EXPRESSION as TARGET:
>     SUITE
> ```

> is semantically equivalent to:
>
> ```
> manager = (EXPRESSION)
> enter = type(manager).__enter__
> exit = type(manager).__exit__
> value = enter(manager)
> hit_except = False
>
> try:
>     TARGET = value
>     SUITE
> except:
>     hit_except = True
>     if not exit(manager, *sys.exc_info()):
>         raise
> finally:
>     if not hit_except:
>         exit(manager, None, None, None)
> ```

So our `yield` expressions are inside the `try` statement implied by the `with` statement.

From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr

> Yield expressions are allowed anywhere in a try construct. If the generator is not resumed before it is finalized (by reaching a zero reference count or by being garbage collected), the generator-iterator’s close() method will be called, allowing any pending finally clauses to execute.

The `finally` clause implied by the `with` statement explicitly calls the `__exit__` method of the context manager, which closes the file.

Answer (score 3):

We can test it. The answer is yes, it is closed.

```py
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def tester():
    try:
        print("enter")
        yield 42
    finally:
        print("exit")
        
       
def generator():
    with tester() as m:
        yield m
        
print(next(generator()))
```

Result:

```
enter
exit
42
```